# Using Mockito to override response of a method and using the passed parameters

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that I want to test:

```
Public String doSomething (MyActivity activity , int number) {

// do some stuff/math calculations
       float aX = number / 3450;
       float bX = aX / 2;
       float cX = bX * 6;

     return activity.getString(R.string.NameOfProduct, cX)
}
```

What I thought about as a test case is to check the calculation, so I testing it the next way :

```
@Test
    public void validDoSomething() throws Exception {

    myObject = Mockito.spy(MyActivity.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<Integer> captor=ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
    MyActivity activity = Mockito.mock(MyActivity.class);
    when(activity.getString(anyInt(),captor.capture())).thenReturn(new Answer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                    return (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            }
        }.toString());

   int x = 9;
   String test =  myObject.validDoSomething (activity, x)

   float aX = x  / 3450;
   float bX = aX / 2;
   float cX = bX * 6;
assertEquals(test ,cX)
    }
```

Because `activity.getString()` goes down and uses Android context and so on so I thought about just returning the calculated parameter and I’ll verify against my (the same) calculation . so I kind of override it.

The thing is in response I’m getting an Object  with the name of the Test/Class… and not the actual parameter that I passed

1. What’s wrong? How can I get the actual response?
2. Is That the right way to test it?

Comment: The answer given by @Ezio is correct. You can also move the activity.getString behind an interface. The interface (StringFetcher or whatever) will have a getProductString method. With mockito you can then mock the return of the interface.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are having so much trouble to test a simple function is because  you have mixed your business logic and UI logic at the same place. I would suggest that you move out the logic that is doing the calculation to a separate function and use the return value of the function in your activity. That way your business logic will be independent of the UI logic and easily testable.

```
public float doSomething ( int number) {
   float aX = number / 3450;
   float bX = aX / 2;
   float cX = bX * 6;
   return cx;
}
```

In your activity: `activity.getString(R.string.NameOfProduct, doSomething(number))`

Comment: That "mixing" is called: **violating** the single responsibility principle ;-)

Comment: @Ezio Any ideas how to handle the returned parameters from that or any other method in the test?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say here? As far as I can understand you want to test if the returned value is correct or not, am I right?

Comment: I want to return the value that was passed to the method + my calculation. for instance if `method(5) ` so I want to return  5*8 every time